Azure Web App can't use Managed Identity when running with Docker
Edit
Do not set the AZURE_CLIENT_ID and AZURE_TENANT_ID environment variables in your web app. Also, when using DefaultAzureCredential, do this: DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_environment_credential = False).
Setup
I have a simple Python app that is deployed as an Azure Web App using Docker. The app itself is running, but can't connect with an Azure SQL Database that is configured to only allow authentication through Managed Identity.
Both myself and the app's Managed Identity have been added to a security group (let's call it my-group). I created the SQL Server hosting the database using az sql server create ... --external-admin-name my-group. After doing so, I also ran these queries:
CREATE USER [my-group] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [my-group];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [my-group];
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin   ADD MEMBER [my-group];

The following code, which is also part of my app, can run locally without Docker, provided I first login using az login. (When using Docker, the app also can't connect to the database, but everything else is working just fine.)
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential


def create_token_struct(databaseToken):
    
    exptoken = b''
    
    for i in bytes(databaseToken[0], "UTF-8"):
        exptoken += bytes({i})
        exptoken += bytes(1)
    
    return struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken


credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

pyodbc.connect(AZURE_SQL_CONNECTION_STRING, attrs_before = {1256: create_token_struct(credential.get_token('https://database.windows.net/'))})


The connection string looks like this: Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:my-server-name.database.windows.net,1433;Database=my_database_name;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30
The error
When running in Azure, the app returns an error the moment it runs that code. At first it just gave a Login timeout expired error, but after adding two environment variables (AZURE_CLIENT_ID and AZURE_TENANT_ID) to my Azure Web App, I now get the following error:
azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:
    EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
Visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot this issue.
    ManagedIdentityCredential: (None) No User Assigned or Delegated Managed Identity found for specified ClientId/ResourceId/PrincipalId.
Code: None
Message: No User Assigned or Delegated Managed Identity found for specified ClientId/ResourceId/PrincipalId.
To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot.

The values of the environment variables are obtained by running az webapp identity show; the AZURE_CLIENT_ID is set to the output's principalId and the AZURE_TENANT_ID is set to the tenantId. I have also tried other values, such as the app's Application ID and the security group's Object Id.
What am I missing here? I can access the database locally, so it seems that, somehow, the Docker container doesn't "receive" the system-assigned managed identity of the Azure Web App.
Edit
Here is my Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10


COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


# For pyodbc
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev

RUN sh -c "curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -" \
    && apt-get update \
    && sh -c "curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list" \
    && apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18 \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18


# Azure CLI
RUN sh -c "curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash"


WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 8501


After enabling System Managed identity in Azure web app, assign the role to Managed identity in the Azure SQL database similar way how you are creating the user for group and assigning the role.

Do you mean I should run CREATE USER for both the security group and the app's managed identity? Why isn't it enough to do it for only the security group and then add the managed identity to that group?

Share your Dockerfile

I've added my Dockerfile to my original post

Running CREATE USER and the ALTER ROLE queries for the app's managed identity  did not work, unfortunately.

What error are you getting ?

This worked for me.
I created a simple flask app to fetch data from table
Dockerfile:
FROM python

RUN sh -c "curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -" \
    && apt-get update \
    && sh -c "curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list" \
    && apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18 \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18

RUN pip install gunicorn

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT [ "gunicorn", "app:app"]

app.py:
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
import azure.identity as ad
import pyodbc
import struct
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello():
    message = "Greetings! Wecome to Flask App"

    try:
        cred = ad.DefaultAzureCredential()
        Connectionstring = "Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:mi-in-docker-server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=manageidentyindocker;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30"
        with pyodbc.connect(Connectionstring,attrs_before = {1256: create_token_struct(cred.get_token('https://database.windows.net/'))}) as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("Select * from Users;")
                data= []
                data = cursor.fetchall()  # Fetch the result

                return str(data)
                
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        return(f"SQL query failed: {e}")
    
def create_token_struct(databaseToken):
    
    exptoken = b''
    
    for i in bytes(databaseToken[0], "UTF-8"):
        exptoken += bytes({i})
        exptoken += bytes(1)
    
    return struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

INPUT:
assigning role to system assigned identity of the web app:

NOTE : you can assign roles when you login using Microsoft Entra Authentication in Azure.

DECLARE @USERNAME nvarchar(128)

SET @USERNAME = 'my-system-assign-identity-name'

BEGIN
    EXECUTE('CREATE USER "' + @USERNAME + '" FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER');
    EXECUTE('ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER "' + @USERNAME + '"');
    EXECUTE('ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER "' + @USERNAME + '"');
    EXECUTE('ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER "' + @USERNAME + '"')
END


Creating table Users

OUTPUT:

For reference check this Q&A post.
